Do we need Apex Test Class for Constants Class?
I have an apex class with just constants. Do I need to write the test class for it?
public class ApexConstants { 
        public static final INTEGER DEFAULT_SIZE= 3;
        public static final STRING ERROR_MESSAGE = 'An error has occurred, please contact System Admininstrator.';
    }


A constants class is something of an anti-pattern. Take a look here for some interesting insights and ways to improve the situation, but then you will need tests...

Thanks @PhilW. The linked post’s answers says we need to have to constant class when it is required and if we have it, use getters for better performance. In that case as  well, do we need to test class for this constant class?

If you have getters, which is what you need for performance, you need to have coverage for these methods. However, that does not have to be done via a specific unit test for the class, but rather by the tests that exercise the code that calls these getters...

Got it! Thanks!! @PhilW

Your class doesn't need its own test class as long as it has test coverage. In this case you should be fine if those constants are used in another class that has test coverage.

Thank you @HAlves. Will try this.
